# Add users in groups in AD on premises from SPFX solution

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am trying to add users to AD Groups; unfortunately MS Graph doesn't work correctly because of the hybrid environment (Azure AD synced with AD on prem). Is there any way to add people to on prem groups in a SPFX React solution ?
I get this error in MS Graph:

```
"{
"error": {
"code": "Request_BadRequest",
"message": "Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration. 
.......}"
```

Also, how fast the sync will work ? The solution will be deployed on SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not supported to update an on prem AD Group with Microsoft Graph API.

To add users into AD group, we need to operate it in the on-premises environment and then sync it to Azure.

Similar posts for your reference:

[Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102799/unable-to-update-the-specified-properties-for-on-premises-mastered-directory-syn)

[On-Premises User Profile Update Using Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646940/on-premises-user-profile-update-using-microsoft-graph-api)